# How to iterate through multiple arrays for every position in the first array iterate the second array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "iostream"

char s[100];
char s1[100];

int i = 0;
int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;

void populate();
void squeeze();

int main()
{
  printf("Write something, hit enter and than write something again. Hit 
  enter to see result\n");

  populate();
  squeeze();

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}

void populate()     // insert chars in two arrays
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
      s[i] = c;
      i++;
  }

  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
      s1[i1] = c;
      i1++;
  }
}

void squeeze()      // iterate the arrays to find if there are same chars
{
  char s2[1000];
  i = 0;
  i1 = 0;

  for (int r = 0; r <= s[i - 1]; r++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j <= s1[i1 - 1]; j++)
      {
        if (s[r] == s1[j])
        {
            s2[i2] = s[r];
            i2++;
        }
      }
  }
  for (int m = 0; m <= s2[i2 - 1]; m++)    //print every element in s2[];
  {
      printf("%c", s2[m]);
  }
}
```

I want to iterate through the second array `s1` for every element in the first array `s` and put the duplicates in the third array `s2`.
For all I found on the net by far is how to iterate through two or more arrays in the same position `arr1[i] = arr2[i]`, `arr1[i1] = arr2[i1]` and so on. This is my code, but from unknown reasons for me it does not work.

Comment: Typo: your `i1 = 0` should be `i2 = 0` in `squeeze()`. By the way `a <= b - 1` is the same as `a < b`  for integers

Comment: Avoid the use of *global variables* unless absolutely necessary. (which when learning C is never) Globals increase the risk for name collisions and variable shadowing problems. This becomes more acute as your code grows in size. Instead, declare needed variables in `main()` and pass them as parameters as required. (it's also a good idea to add the `-Wshadow` option to your compile string) While globals have their place, their use should be a rare exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: You should write `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include "iostream"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  i = 0;
  i1 = 0;
```

You are losing the length of the arrays `s` and `s1`. And then you access array index out of bound invoking Undefined behavior.(in `squeeze`).

The correct way to do it would be

```
void squeeze(void)      // iterate the arrays to find if there are same chars
{
  char s2[1000];

  for (size_t r = 0; r < i; r++)
  {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < i1; j++)
      {
        if (s[r] == s1[j])
        {
            s2[i2] = s[r];
            i2++;
        }
      }
  }
  for (size_t m = 0; m < i2; m++)    //print every element in s2[];
  {
      printf("%c", s2[m]);
  }
}
```

#### Few points to note:

- Use global variables are not needed here. You yourself made the mistake of modifying a global variable. With time in large codes using too many global variables makes it less maintainable and readable.
- Know how to pass parameter in a function. And also look into functions like `fgets` which serves the purpose of input in your case.
- Check these two resources. These will help you a lot

  1. [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
  2. [Definitive C books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Yup... this gives me the correct result. Thanks again.